# Swift 3 alamofire + SWXMLHash

Tags: xml, swift, swift3, alamofire, swxmlhash

In Swift 2 had a method that could parse xml response, but its not working in Swift 3.

Here is my Swift 2.0 method:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "www.example.com", headers: headers)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in

            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data!)
            let e21Time = xml["tabless"]["tables"][0]["UPDATE_TIME"].element?.text
}
```

can anyone help me with Swift 3 code please?

Comment: Which guy is not working, Alamofire or SWXMLHash?

Comment: well they are both working in swift 3 but I cannot get XML variable from alamofire to work with SWXMLHash

Comment: I'll give you a down vote.  I suggest you rephrase your question so that people won't get confused by your question.

Answer (score 0):

I did not recognize that Alamofire does not contain (request, response, data, error) parameters anymore but just (response) so... this is the solution.

Swift 3

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.eu/info.php", method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in        
     let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(response.data!)
}
```